# How to get data from the internet for use with matplotlib?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, urllib

I'm following Sentdex' tutorials for mathplotlib, and i'm stuck at this video: #8 getting data from the internet: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IbUa1tTT-7k&t=625s

the provided code looks like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import urllib
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
def graph_data(stock):
stock_price_url = http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/'+stock+'/chartdata;type=quote;range=10y/csv'

source_code = urllib.request.urlopen(stock_price_url).read().decode()

stock_data = []
split_source = source_code.split('\n')

for line in split_source:
    split_line = line.split(',')
    if len(split_line) == 6:
        if 'values' not in line:
            stock_data.append(line)
```

Apparently the yahoo.api doesn't work anymore. I tried to find some different source, but if I use another url, I get an 'invalid character' error in any case.
I also tried urllib3 and couldn't/shouldn't I use the requests module?
I don't care if it's finance, sports or weather data, but I'd be glad, if I could continue with this tutorial, or if you could point out a better alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't worry about doing the exact same thing as the instructor did.
use alternatives. if not stock why not some data from unicef or who?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import urllib, json
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

url = 'https://data.cityofchicago.org/resource/f7f2-ggz5.json?fuel_type_code=LPG'
# from https://dev.socrata.com/consumers/getting-started.html
a = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode()
print (a)
```

You have some data to play with now. you can find more from
https://www.forbes.com/sites/bernardmarr/2016/02/12/big-data-35-brilliant-and-free-data-sources-for-2016/#24627925b54d

OR

you can just download the csv file of TSLA stock for 10 years here
http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/tsla/historical
then import it as csv. instead of reading from the net, you will be reading from the file. It won't be same but it will be better than nothing.